# When I need to run mapReduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm newbie with MongoDB.

I have created a `mapReduce` on my `Person` collection to group `cities`.

```
db.Person.find()
[{
    name: 'Bob',
    addresses: [
        {
            street: 'Vegas Street',
            neighborhood: {
                name: 'Center',
                city: {
                    name: 'Springfield'
                }
            }
        }, {
           .....
        }
    ]
}, {
   ....
}]
```

And this is my `mapReduce`:

```
db.Person.mapReduce(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.address.length-1; i++) {
        var address = this.address[i];
        emit(address.neighborhood.city.name, 1);
    }
}, function(k, v) {
    return v.length;
}, { out: 'City' });
```

Then I use this to list my cities:

```
db.City.find().sort({'_id:', 1})
[{
    _id: 'Springfield',
    value: 3
}, { 
    _id: 'City B',
    value: 2
}, { 
    ...
}]
```

My question is about the `City` data, I need run the `mapReduce` each time I insert, update or delete on my `Person`collection or it runs automatically?

Comment: Why do you think you need `mapReduce`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user3100115 I need `mapReduce` to group some data inside my collection, I will describe it on the question.

Comment: Show us sample documents with the expected result and we tell you what you need to do.

Comment: @user3100115 please take a look now.